# Save a list of objects in django

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-orm, django-1.5

I am using django 1.5 and i am trying to do something like this :

```
    quotes = formset.save()
    user = client_form.save()
    for quote in quotes:
        quote.client = user
    quotes.save()
```

But lists dont have a save() method so is there some built in functionality to do something similar ?

I found this nswer on SO [Question about batch save objects in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4216192/question-about-batch-save-objects-in-django)

Is it still True with django 1.5 ?
Is there no way to avoid the save() call on each object of the list ?

here is my actual view code:

```
def new_quote(request):
    QuoteLineFormSet = modelformset_factory(QuoteLine, form=QuoteLineForm, extra=2)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        formset = QuoteLineFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES, queryset=QuoteLine.objects.none())
        quote_form = QuoteForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if formset.is_valid() and quote_form.is_valid():
            quote_lines = formset.save(commit=False)
            #quote_lines = formset.get_queryset()
            quote = quote_form.save()
            for quote_line in quote_lines:
                quote_line.quote = quote
                quote_line.save()
            request.session['quote_id'] = quote.id
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('new_client'))
    else:
        formset = QuoteLineFormSet(queryset=QuoteLine.objects.none())
        quote_form = QuoteForm()

    return render(request, 'request_quote_form.html', {
        'formset': formset,
        'quote_form': quote_form,
    })
```

My solution for now

```
    quote_line_ids = [item.pk for item in formset.save()]
    quote_lines_qs = QuoteLine.objects.filter(pk__in=quote_line_ids)
    quote = quote_form.save()
    quote_lines_qs.update(quote=quote)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do `formset.save()`, it hits database as many times as number of forms in the formset. So, its `n` hits if the number of element in the formset is `n`.

So, you can have `commit=False` on the formset which will not hit the db at all. Then you can update the objects and call `save()` on each object. So, your database calls remain `n` times.

```
#doesn't hit the database at all
quotes = formset.save(commit=False)
user = client_form.save()
for quote in quotes:
    quote.client = user
    #hits the db
    quote.save()
```

Not sure if you can do this entire operation in one call to db.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`update()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#update) method on a queryset.

Also see this question and answer: [Django: form that updates X amount of models](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3778585/django-form-that-updates-x-amount-of-models/3779224#3779224)

Comment: useful but i don't use a queryset

Comment: how ? i tried a few things but formset.get_queryset() always return an empty list

Comment: Thank you. That's because you're setting an empty queryset while initializing `QuoteLineFormSet` (see [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#changing-the-queryset)). So, my solution won't work in your case, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Also have look at this [link](http://ole-laursen.blogspot.nl/2010/11/bulk-inserting-django-objects.html). Very straightforward easy-to-use approach. From the blog:

```
for x in seq:
   o = SomeObject()
   o.foo = x
   o.save()
```

becomes

```
l = []
for x in seq:
    o = SomeObject()
    o.foo = x
    l.append(o)
insert_many(l)
```

Comment: i would like to avoid some third party code if it is possible